# Document starts having heaps of errors in the middle, but the code doesn't have any problems in it

Tags: errors, lists

I have a 40 page long document that works fine for the most part, but starts having heaps of errors on different lines by the end. The document has a total of 42 errors, happening on several lines, and one line usually has 10-15 errors. The document compiles fine, and it looks as it's supposed to, but it still bothers me to have the errors, and why I have them, so help would be appreciated.

I simplified the document to share here, as requested by comments, and now it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,pdftex]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel} %needed in Hungarian reports
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for the nice header
\usepackage{graphicx} %grapics input
\usepackage{tikz} %tikz figures
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} % szövegbeli kommentekhez, szövegdobozokhoz
\usepackage{comment} %többsoros kommentekhez
\usepackage{textgreek} %görög betűk math mode-on kívül
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % felső és alsó indexekhez
\usepackage{siunitx} %szép celsius jelért
\usepackage{t1enc} %mert kéri...
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} %hogy a képaláírások középen legyenek
\usepackage{array} % hogy a táblázat oszlopainak szélességét állítsam
\usepackage{tabu} % ez meg auomatikusan kitölti a táblázatot oldalszélesre

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,pdftex]{geometry} %margins

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref} %links
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=red,
unicode=true
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Results\label{results}}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

This version has 13 errors, all on line 47 (the `\clearpage` line). Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@fixname #1->\begingroup \def \bbl@tempe 
                                             {l@}\edef \bbl@tempd {\noexpand...
l.47 \clearpage

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Argument of \bbl@tempd has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.47 \clearpage

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\noexpand \@ifundefined {\noexpand \bbl@tempe \languagename }}\bbl@tempd \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \bbl@tempd was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.47 \clearpage

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Use of \begingroup doesn't match its definition.
<to be read again> ...MAGYAR{{1}}\begingroup \def 
                                                  {L@}\edef \par 
l.47 \clearpage

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Missing { inserted.
\MakeUppercase  ... {\uppercase {#1}}\reserved@a }

l.47 \clearpage

Where was the left brace? You said something like `\def\a}',
which I'm going to interpret as `\def\a{}'.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.47 \clearpage

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@begin@tempboxa ...begingroup #2\color@endgroup }
                                                  \def \width {\wd \@tempbox...
l.47 \clearpage

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...adwidth }{\raggedleft \f@nch@orh }}}
                                                  \headrule 
l.47 \clearpage

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\headrule ...width \plainheadrulewidth \fi \hrule 
                                                  \@height \headrulewidth \@...
l.47 \clearpage

To put a horizontal rule in an hbox or an alignment,
you should use \leaders or \hrulefill (see The TeXbook).

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.47 \clearpage

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.47 \clearpage

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.47 \clearpage

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.47 \clearpage

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.47 \clearpage

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.47 \clearpage

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@outputpage ...or \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead }
                                                  \color@endbox }\dp \@tempb...
l.47 \clearpage

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Not sure if it matters, but I'm writing in an online editor (overleaf).

Comment: Well you will have to show a small but complete document and the complete error message (copy it from the log-file. Your snippets are not enough to investigate.

Comment: it is impossible to help given the information that you show, Firstly show the exact error message from the log file, from `!` to `?` in a code section so line endings are preserved, then also do not just post fragments, post a small complete document that makes the error,

Comment: in particular for undefined control sequences the error message tells you _which command is undefined_ if you showed that, someone may be able to suggest a package that defines the command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can try to isolate the problem by removing content from your document, what you have already started to do by removing the `enumerate`. Remove as much as you can until you have a small document left (e.g., 1 page or less). If during the removing the error disappears then leave that part in and remove something else. When you have a small document, you can post the code here together with the full error message - then you will most likely get a quick reply that solves your problem.

Comment: @Marijn  I've updated the post as per your and the others' recommendations. I've tried to simplify the document as much as possible. With it, the number of errors also decreased, but there's still quite a few. I've included them all.

Comment: @WandaW. thanks for your update, it is very helpful. The problem is in the line `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}` in combination with `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`, removing any of these two solves the issue. Obviously you need `magyar` for writing in Hungarian, but this might be a good place tstarting point to look for solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load `fancyhdr` before `babel` when the option `magyar` is used (as directed by a warning issued by the language definition file). However, this conflicts somehow with `\MakeUppercase`.

Either you redefine `\sectionmark` to avoid it, or load `textcase` with the `overload` option.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for the nice header
\usepackage[magyar]{babel} %needed in Hungarian reports
\usepackage{graphicx} %grapics input
\usepackage{tikz} %tikz figures
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} % szövegbeli kommentekhez, szövegdobozokhoz
\usepackage{comment} %többsoros kommentekhez
\usepackage{textgreek} %görög betűk math mode-on kívül
%\usepackage{fixltx2e} % felső és alsó indexekhez
\usepackage{siunitx} %szép celsius jelért
%\usepackage{t1enc} %mert kéri...
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} %hogy a képaláírások középen legyenek
\usepackage{array} % hogy a táblázat oszlopainak szélességét állítsam
\usepackage{tabu} % ez meg auomatikusan kitölti a táblázatot oldalszélesre
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  headheight=13.6pt,
]{geometry} %margins

%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref} %links
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  citecolor=red,
  unicode=true
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Results\label{results}}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

I also made a few changes: I removed the option `pdftex` everywhere, which should not generally be used; instead of `t1enc` it's better to load `fontenc`; loading `color` is useless if `xcolor` is used; `fixltx2e` is included in the latest releases of LaTeX; `url` is loaded by `hyperref`.

Finally, I added a setting to `headheight`, as directed by `fancyhdr`.